# Combine logs of kibana base on unique id

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-6

I have Kibana 6.6.1 connected to es, that contains logs.Each log has host, time and message.

For example:

```
host   date      level  message
node-1 10.1.2019 ERROR  could not fetch image
node-2 10.1.2019 INFO   working fine
node-1 10.1.2019 INFO   downloaded file
node-1 10.1.2019 ERROR  could not fetch image
```

Is it possible in kibana to view base on the host? i.e. each host will have raw, and you could download the all logs of the host. something like:

```
host    
node-1           download logs of node 1
node-2           download logs of node 2
```

Answer (score 0):

To drill down to a specific host you just need to apply the right filter in *Discover*:

[image]

Then you will need to `Save` this specific visualization and after that you can `Share` -> `CSV Reports` -> `Generate CSV`. Once finished (will be generated in a background task), you can download the CSV.